# Excel count base row and column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel , I have a table like this in Sheet1:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **symbol** | **tag1** | **tag2** | **tag3** |
| 2 | **BTC** | vcf | kcf |  |
| 3 | **ETH** | kcf | gbp | ddd |

and another table in Sheet2 like as:

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **tag** | **vcf** | **kcf** | **gbp** | **ddd** |
| 2 | **vcf** | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | **kcf** | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | **gbp** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | **ddd** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The values are count of symbols that have both corresponding tags.
How can I calculate values of table 2 by formula without VBA?

Comment: Why is kcf/ddd 0?

Comment: You need to explain the logic/calculation there is in this process. Just showing values it's not a good practice to understand properly what you need.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I said logic in the last line. For each pair of tags the value shows count of symbols that have both tags. As Ike said, value for kcf/ddd and ddd/kcf must be 1 because one symbol (ETH) exists that has both tags kcf and ddd

Comment: Wouldn't kcf/kcf have 2 then instead of 1 since two symbols have "both" corresponding tag(s)?

Comment: @Notus_Panda you are right. Any suggestion for formula?

Comment: @AliM67 have you got time to review yet?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I have not over complicated the solution, however if one using `MS365` then could use the following formula:

The following solution illustrates the pre edited version of the OP:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _tags, BYROW($B$2:$D$3,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,x))),
     _one, FIND(","&$F2&",",","&_tags&","),
     _two, FIND(","&G$1&",",","&_tags&","),
     SUM(COUNT(_one*_two)>=1))
```

---

Or, The following solution illustrates the post edited version of the OP:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _tags, BYROW($B$2:$D$3,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,x))),
     _one, FIND(","&$F2&",",","&_tags&","),
     _two, FIND(","&G$1&",",","&_tags&","),
     COUNT(_one*_two))
```

---

Or, Use `MAKEARRAY()` to spill the whole array using one single input dynamic array formula:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _tagsr, F2:F5,
     _tagsc, G1:J1,
     _tagss, BYROW(B2:D3,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",1,x))),
     _rows, ROWS(_tagsr),
     _columns, COLUMNS(_tagsc),
     MAKEARRAY(_rows,_columns,LAMBDA(r,c, COUNT(
                             FIND(","&INDEX(_tagsr,r)&",",","&_tagss&",")*
                             FIND(","&INDEX(_tagsc,c)&",",","&_tagss&",")))))
```

---

For `Traditional Excel` aka `Excel 2010` I would use a helper column(Long forgotten these days mostly use `MS365`). That said, one could use the following:

[image]

---

Firstly add one helper/auxiliary column at the end, use this formula as shown in screenshot.

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
 =TRIM(" "&B2&" "&C2&" "&D2&" ")
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=COUNT(FIND(" "&$G2&" "," "&$E$2:$E$3&" ")*
  FIND(" "&H$1&" "," "&$E$2:$E$3&" "))
```

---

Both the above formulas needs to be filled down, and for the latter a bit more to fill right as well as is required.

---

Comment: I have not using Microsoft 365. I need a formula in Excel 2010